# Why am I getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'color'?

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have a class city. In that, i have parameter color. And i try to call it in functions coloring. Pleas have a look at the code

```
class city:
    def __init__(self,name,color=None, choise = ['r','g','b']):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.choise = choise
    def  __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "{} {}".format(self.name,self.color)    


def coloring(S):
        if S.color == None: #this line warning AttributeError
            S.color = S.choise[0]

def Mapcolor(S = city(name = 'a')):
    coloring(S)
```

This is the stack trace

```
File "d:\Thực hành\Thực hành 1\exaample.py", line 29, in <module>
    Mapcolor("wa")
  File "d:\Thực hành\Thực hành 1\exaample.py", line 27, in Mapcolor
    coloring(S)
  File "d:\Thực hành\Thực hành 1\exaample.py", line 23, in coloring
    if S.color == None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'color'
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are calling `Mapcolor("xyz")` with a string, when the Mapcolor function requires a city e.g. `Mapcolor(city("xyz"))`.

Comment: You call `Mapcolor("wa")`. Why do you pass in a `str` instead of a `city`?

Comment: You are passing a string to `Mapcolor`, not a `city`.  There's no code to convert the string to a `city` object.